# Verifying inputs and repeating statements

Tags: c, linux

I need to take two numbers from two separate scans and find the GCD of both of them. I have this currently which will take the two numbers, but I need to validate input with a function. It should work as follows, I enter a number and it checks to verify that it is a positive integer. If not it should prompt me to say that the input is unrecognized and ask for it again. Once I input a valid number, it should continue to ask me to put in a second one and do the same verification process. Any help with input validation and repeating the question in a function would be helpful.

```
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, i, GCD;
   
    printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
    scanf("%d" ,&num1);
    printf("Please enter a positive integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
if (num1 >0 && num2 > 0) {
    for(i = 1; i <= num1 && i <= num2; i++)
    {
        if(num1 % i == 0 && num2 % i == 0)
            GCD = i;
    }
}
else {
   printf("I'm sorry that number is unrecognized or negative.\n");

}
printf("The largest integer that divides both %d and %d is: %d\n",num1,num2, GCD);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about doing the `scanf` in a while loop, and think about the loop's condition...

Comment: @SHG I thought about that, but how would I return to asking for the input again without it getting all jumbled up?

Comment: Getting the input will happen inside the loop body, and as long as it's not valid (i.e. not a positive integer) the loop body will keep getting executed. You should add what you thought about to the code in the question and then people can help with more specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a do-while loop and put your scanf in there as long as you dont get a valid answer. For example:

```
do {

   // put your scans here 

} while(num1<0 || num2<0);
```

Also you can catch the case if he inputs a character instead of integer input! So that is a good way to repeat a prompt until you get the valid answer.